# ORA-00937 not a single-group group function converted from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm getting an `ORA-00937` error when running the following ORACLE statement, I'm very new to Oracle (T-SQL is more my bag). I've converted a select statement previously written in SQL I'm at a loss as to why it's expecting a group by ... as all columns are sum'd. This is the converted select statement (I'm currently running/ testing these using SQLPLUS) :

```
select 
round(COALESCE(
(COALESCE((select SUM((F_BOOK_DATES.BKD_ADATE_ENDS - F_BOOK_DATES.BKD_ADATE_START) * (60 * 24)) FROM F_BOOK_DATES 
INNER JOIN F_BOOK_HEADER ON F_BOOK_DATES.BKD_FKEY_BK_SEQ = F_BOOK_HEADER.BK_SEQ 
and EXTRACT (YEAR from F_BOOK_DATES.BKD_DATE_START ) = EXTRACT (YEAR from SYSDATE )
and EXTRACT (MONTH from F_BOOK_DATES.BKD_DATE_START ) = EXTRACT (MONTH from SYSDATE )
and EXTRACT (DAY from F_BOOK_DATES.BKD_DATE_START ) = EXTRACT (DAY from SYSDATE )
AND F_BOOK_HEADER.BK_STATUS NOT IN ('CX','TP')
AND F_BOOK_HEADER.Deleted <> 1
AND F_BOOK_DATES.Deleted <> 1),9999999999.99,0)
/sum(case when FAREALO.AllDayBooking = 1 then 1400 else
((FAREALO.LO_TIME_END - FAREALO.LO_TIME_START) * (60 * 24)) end) * 100),0),2) as "PercentUtilised"
from FAREALO
inner join F_LO_TYPE on FAREALO.LO_FKEY_LOT_SEQ = F_LO_TYPE.LOT_SEQ
where FAREALO.LO_BK_LOCATION = 1
and LOT_CBS = 1;
```

This is the SQL statement (that works) that I tried to convert above:

```
select 
round(isnull(
(isnull(convert (DECIMAL(10,2),(select SUM(datediff(n,BKD_ADATE_START, BKD_ADATE_ENDS)) FROM F_BOOK_DATES with (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN F_BOOK_HEADER with (NOLOCK) ON BKD_FKEY_BK_SEQ = BK_SEQ 
AND DATEPART(YYYY,BKD_DATE_START) = DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(MM,BKD_DATE_START) = DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(DD,BKD_DATE_START) = DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())
AND BK_STATUS NOT IN ('CX','TP')
AND F_BOOK_HEADER.Deleted <> 1
AND F_BOOK_DATES.Deleted <> 1)),0)
/
sum(case when AllDayBooking = 1 then 1400 else
datediff(n,LO_TIME_START, LO_TIME_END) end) * 100),0),2) as PercentUtilised
from FAREALO with (NOLOCK)
inner join F_LO_TYPE with (NOLOCK) on LO_FKEY_LOT_SEQ = LOT_SEQ
where LO_BK_LOCATION = 1
and LOT_CBS = 1
```

Anybody see what I've missed?

Thanks

J

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to include the table definitions?  I can't tell what columns belong to which tables.  Also, does it help if you identify all of the columns in your query with the table they come from (e.g. instead of writing `BK_STATUS`, write `F_BOOK_HEADER.BK_STATUS`, and so on)?

Comment: I've added full table defs to the above Oracle query.
Though having added MIN to the first part of the sum (3rd line, since this part was bringing back the same value numerous times), the query now runs

Answer (score 0):

Here's the altered query which runs fine, after adding the MIN function:

```
select 
round(COALESCE(
(COALESCE(MIN((select SUM((BKD_ADATE_ENDS - BKD_ADATE_START) * (60 * 24)) FROM F_BOOK_DATES 
INNER JOIN F_BOOK_HEADER ON BKD_FKEY_BK_SEQ = BK_SEQ 
and EXTRACT (YEAR from BKD_DATE_START ) = EXTRACT (YEAR from SYSDATE )
and EXTRACT (MONTH from BKD_DATE_START ) = EXTRACT (MONTH from SYSDATE )
and EXTRACT (DAY from BKD_DATE_START ) = EXTRACT (DAY from SYSDATE )
AND BK_STATUS NOT IN ('CX','TP')
AND F_BOOK_HEADER.Deleted <> 1
AND F_BOOK_DATES.Deleted <> 1)),9999999999.99,0)
/sum(case when AllDayBooking = 1 then 1400 else
((LO_TIME_END - LO_TIME_START) * (60 * 24)) end) * 100),0),2) as "PercentUtilised"
from FAREALO
inner join F_LO_TYPE on LO_FKEY_LOT_SEQ = LOT_SEQ
where LO_BK_LOCATION = 1
and LOT_CBS = 1;
```